# How to get line number of the IASTNode using cdt APIs

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am using CDT parser to read .c/.h/.cpp files. To get the line number of a variable/macro/function, i am using **getStartingLineNumber(IASTNoder iastNode)** of **ASTNodes** class. But the line number which is returned from the method is not correct. I think the method is not considering the empty lines in the input files(.c/.h/.cpp). 
Can some one help me in getting correct line numbers of the code.

Example:
**iastNode** is instance of **IASTFunctionDefinition** 
int lineNumber = ASTNodes.getStartingLineNumber(**iastNode**);

Thanks you so much in advance.

Comment: This method should return the correct line number. If you're finding it doesn't, could you please provide a complete (entire file) example?

Comment: /* BusyWait.c <br>
 *<br>
 * sdfsdafsdaf<br>
 * dsfsdaf<br>
 *<br>
 */<br>
<br>
<br>
static volatile uint32 LoopsInTwoMilliseconds;<br>
<br>
static volatile Os_StopwatchTickType t0, t1, t2;<br>
<br>
#ifndef GUESS_LOOPS_PER_MS<br>
  #define GUESS_LOOPS_PER_MS (20UL)<br>
#endif<br>

Comment: @HighCommander4:  i am trying to fetch the line number for macro GUESS_LOOPS_PER_MS. Original line number in the snippet is 14. But the return value from the CDT API is 10. In the above snippet i had put <br> for each line separator

Comment: Could you also describe how you obtain the node on which you call `getStartingLineNumber()`?

Comment: CDOM instance = CDOM.getInstance();
IASTServiceProvider service = instance.getASTService();
ICodeReaderFactory codeReaderFactory = instance.getCodeReaderFactory(CDOM.PARSE_SAVED_RESOURCES);
IASTTranslationUnit translationUnit = service.getTranslationUnit(iFileCreatedFromCfile, codeReaderFactory);
IASTPreprocessorStatement[] preprocessorStatements = translationUnit.getAllPreprocessorStatements();
int lineNumber = ASTNodes.getStartingLineNumber(preprocessorStatements[0]);
System.out.println(lineNumber);

Comment: What CDT version are you using? `CDOM` and `IASTServiceProvider` have been deprecated for a long time, and the current implementation of `getCodeReaderFactory()` [always returns null](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/src/org/eclipse/cdt/core/dom/CDOM.java#n85).

Comment: [This  patch](https://gist.github.com/HighCommander4/d824da67dd2900fe1c23c9b9d3495677) applies to CDT master, and adds a testcase that contains your example code and prints the line number of the code in question. It prints 13 when I run it, and the first preprocessor statement is indeed on the 13th line of the file, so that seems all good me.

Comment: I am not clear on how i can write the test case which you have provided. Can you please provide me the snippet on how to get IASTTranslationUnit object for a single .c file.

Comment: I would need to understand more about what it is that you are writing - an Eclipse plugin? a standalone RCP application? Also, as this is getting off-topic from "how to get the line number of an IASTNode", please ask a new question about it.

Comment: I have eclipse plugin. In navigator two same C files of different versions are present. I have to generate html report with compare information between the two version of files. I am able to do compare the data from IASTNode elements. I should also show the line number in html report where the change is present.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but please see also my request to ask a **new question** about this new topic.